# Mongoose populating array inside nested schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

This is my schema:

```
var userSchema = {
  folders           : [ folderSchema ],
  ...
}

var folderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  itemlist      : [{ type: String, ref: 'Item', required: true }],
  foldername    : { type: String},
  ...
});

// Item model
var itemSchema = {
  name: { type: String },
  ...
}
```

I would like to populate itemlist (entire array) inside of each folderSchema, is this possible?

What I've tried so far but doesn't work:

```
userModel.findOne({ _id: userId }, null, callback).populate({
  path: 'folders.$.itemlist',
  select: 'name'
});
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488712/mongoose-nested-ref-models-population) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042284/mongoose-nested-reference-population) are similar but they store the folder models and have a ref instead of nested document.

Bonus: is it possible to select only some folders by foldername to populate their itemlist?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for "deep population", see the [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) section "Populating across multiple levels"

rewrite your populate to:

```
userModel.findOne({ _id: userId }, null, callback).populate({
  path: 'folders',
  populate: { path : 'itemlist'}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to actually retrieve the nested folder and perform a find manually. Then simply call find({_id: {$in : folder}}); to find all elements of array.